# use Owin OAuth 2.0 in multi tenant site

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I am currently using Owin 2.0 in my multi tenant CMS. I need a way to change the facebook app id and secret depending on the tenant.

The problem is that Owin config code is executed before anything else. Request.Url is not the solution. Please suggest me a practical solution. Currently i can only differentiate between tenants from the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this answer as a helpful tip and not a solution**

You should use `FacebookAuthenticationProvider` to customize complete flow for each tenant. `FacebookAuthenticationProvider` has three events exposed that will help customization.

*Tip: Use Object Browser in Visual Studio*

```
FacebookAuthenticationOptions fbOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions();
fbOptions.AppId = "DefaultAppId"; 
fbOptions.AppSecret = "DefaultSecret"; 
fbOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("DefaultTenantWithCallBackUrl"); 
fbOptions.Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
{
    OnApplyRedirect = (FacebookApplyRedirectContext context) =>
    {
         /*a way to change the facebook app id and secret depending on the tenant.*/
         /*Redirect to tenant specific built url */
    },
    OnAuthenticated = (FacebookAuthenticatedContext context) =>
    {
         /*process tenant specific logic*/
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    },
    OnReturnEndpoint = (FacebookReturnEndpointContext context) =>
    {
         /*process tenant specific logic*/
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
};
app.Use(typeof(FacebookAuthenticationMiddleware), app, fbOptions);
```